# Export to CSV using Reporting Services Express 2008 R2

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Advanced Services, with Reporting Services properly configured. I need to be able to export certain reports to CSV, however this is [unsupported in the Express edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281020.aspx).

My question is: are there any workarounds/alternatives to generate a CSV from a report? I have thought of some options that range from running the same query and generating the CSV independently from the report (my issue here would be maintainability because I'll have the same query in two different places), to writing a custom rendering extension to perform the export (from what I have read this is more complex than it sounds). I'll be running the reports using the ReportViewer control within a form. So, any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like your first option of creating the .csv independently. It's relatively easy to create in code, and gives you a lot of flexibility. To address the duplication of the query, create a Stored procedure and call that from both your code and your report.

Apparently implementing a Rendering extension involves implementing literally hundreds of functions to support all item types, so I don't think you want to head down that path.